# From bash script how to tell when & process finishes

Tags: bash

I am attempting to kick off multiple commands in a bash script but wait for them to complete

It looks something like this:

```
A &
B &
C &
D
```

Unfortunately i don't know which of these processes will finish first.  But i need the whole script to complete when finished with all processes.

So like a rookie i tried:

```
(A &
B &
C &
D) && E
```

Unfortunately `E` only execs after `D` completes.  I would like it if i could get `E` to happen after A - D exec

Hopefully that sums the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
A &
B &
C &
D &
wait
E
```

From the `help` listing:

```
wait: wait [-n] [id ...]
    Wait for job completion and return exit status.

    Waits for each process identified by an ID, which may be a process ID or a
    job specification, and reports its termination status.  If ID is not
    given, waits for all currently active child processes, and the return
    status is zero.  If ID is a a job specification, waits for all processes
    in that job's pipeline.

    If the -n option is supplied, waits for the next job to terminate and
    returns its exit status.

    Exit Status:
    Returns the status of the last ID; fails if ID is invalid or an invalid
    option is given.
```

Comment: I am not allowed to accept an answer in 7 minutes. Ill accept this shortly

Answer (score 0):

`wait(1)` is the canonical solution, but I've used a q&d solution in the past:

```
( A & B & C & D & ) | cat; E
```